# How do I access a table <td> via refs instead of id in React.js

Tags: reactjs

How do I access a refs instead of an id defined in a td of a table? For example, in my React component, I have a td with id="myId". Please see code below:

```
`componentDidUpdate() {
   if (document.getElementById('myId')) {
     // I want to use refs instead of id here. How do I do that?
     document.getElementById('myId').click();
    }
 }`

 `return (
    <div>
       <table width="90%" height="90%">
          <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>{this.props.something}</td>
               <td id="myId" onClick={() => this.props.someFunctionToRun()}>Click me
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div> 
  );`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `ref` prop on `td`. Pass a internal argument as reference and assign to variable you want (i.e. `this.nameInput`)

To use it as DOM element, you must define it in constructor using `.createRef()` method.

Like :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nameInput = React.createRef(); // define ref
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.nameInput) {
    // Use DOM element's native method here
    this.nameInput.click();
    }
}

return (
    <div>
        <table width="90%" height="90%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.something}</td>
                <td ref={input => {
            this.nameInput = input;
    }}  onClick={() => this.props.someFunctionToRun()}>Click me
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
);
```

Comment: Then how do i access this ref from `componentDidUpdate() {
   if (document.getElementById('myId')) {
     document.getElementById('myId').click();
    }
 }`  I need to do an auto click on that <td>. Could you please provide complete example?

Comment: I want to replace “document.getElementById('myId')” in “document.getElementById('myId').click()” with refs as well. Is this the correct syntax? this.refs.nameInput.click();

Comment: Okay, then you need to create ref and define it in constructor. Have updated the answer again

Comment: Ok great. I will try your solution tomorrow and see if it works. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure let me know then